# Algorithm to sort data by ratings

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math

I have data of places that can be rated from 1 to 5 by users. The top rated ones will appear first. But if a place has a `5` stars rating with just `one` rating it will appear before the places that have `4.5` stars for with `1k` rating which i see that it's unfair. I searched for weighted average but i didn't find a real solution.

Comment: *"I searched for weighted average but i didn't find a real solution."*: what was wrong with what you found? Please share what you found and what is wrong with it.

Comment: I found the imdb rating formula. You can find it here [link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMDb#Rankings)

Comment: I don't want to specify a required number of ratings

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities, but in many of them, the expression to sort by will be a function of both the number of stars and the number of ratings.

Here are some example functions you could try:

- f(stars, ratings) = stars * ratings
- f(stars, ratings) = stars * log(ratings)
- f(stars, ratings) = stars * sqrt(ratings)
- f(stars, ratings) = stars * log(sqrt(ratings))
- f(stars, ratings) = stars * log(1 + log(ratings))

...etc.